# horizontally repeated picture twitches when using .animate() to move it in y direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am coding a loading screen with a div that slowly moves out of the screen. But it is twitching for reasons I do not know.

This is the code I am talking about:

```js
function fadeLoadingScreen() {
  $('#loadingBanner').animate({
      bottom: "-15%",
      opacity: 0
    },
    2000,

    function() {
      $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  fadeLoadingScreen();
});
```

```css
#loadingDiv {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10000;
}
#loadingBanner {
  background-image: url("http://images.gofreedownload.net/thumps/crown-pattern-banner-erected-europeanstyle-vector-89228.jpg");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loadingDiv">
  <div id="loadingBanner"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71btwr2j/

can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save and the jsfiddle link contains an error (it also doesn't work on https because of the picture.

http://jsfiddle.net/71btwr2j/2/

Comment: Try defining the height in pixels instead of a percentage.

Comment: ok, that made it work. Any explanation why this happens?